# .lua error 'then' expected near 'else'

Tags: lua

I am having this error, can't find the error.

```
    local choice_revive = {function(player,choice)
  local user_id = vRP.getUserId(player)
  if user_id ~= nil then
    vRPclient.getNearestPlayer(player,{10},function(nplayer)
      local nuser_id = vRP.getUserId(nplayer)
      if nuser_id ~= nil then
        vRPclient.isInComa(nplayer,{}, function(in_coma)
          if in_coma then
            if vRP.tryGetInventoryItem(user_id,"medkit",1,true) else
            vRP.tryGetInventoryItem(user_id,"smartwatch",1,true)
            io.write("Smartwatch: Tilkalder Ambulance")
                then
              vRPclient.playAnim(player,{false,revive_seq,false}) -- anim
              SetTimeout(15000, function()
                vRPclient.varyHealth(nplayer,{50}) -- heal 50
              end)
            end
          else
            vRPclient.notify(player,{lang.emergency.menu.revive.not_in_coma()})
          end
        end)
      else
        vRPclient.notify(player,{lang.common.no_player_near()})
      end
    end)
  end
end,lang.emergency.menu.revive.description()}
```

I have tried to make, and look for error, but without luck.
- If anyone can fix it, tell me please.

Comment: Confused `else` and `then` in 9 and 12 lines, maybe

Comment: [No obvious deficiencies](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/21638-there-are-two-ways-of-constructing-a-software-design-one). [Problem: You have an expression that is hard to understand.](https://refactoring.guru/extract-variable)

Answer (score 1):

if statement, functions and for statement must be ended with **end**.

this code must be like that

```
--Settings--
local Tunnel = module("vrp", "lib/Tunnel")
local Proxy = module("vrp", "lib/Proxy")

vRP = Proxy.getInterface("vRP")
vRPclient = Tunnel.getInterface("vRP","vRP_smartwatch")

if in_coma then
    vRP.tryGetInventoryItem(user_id,"smartwatch",1,true)
    io.write("Smartwatch: Tilkalder Ambulance")
end
function vRP.sendServiceAlert(sender, emergency,x,y,z, msg)
  local service = services[service_name]
  local answered = false
  if service then
    local players = {}
    for k,v in pairs(vRP.rusers) do
      local player = vRP.getUserSource(tonumber(k))
      -- check user
      if vRP.hasPermission(k,service.alert_permission) and player ~= nil then
        table.insert(players,player)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: File:2: attempt to call a nil value (global 'module')

Comment: This is a different issue and should have a different question. You will need to check the documentation for the system that is providing the environment that your scripts are running in. Some systems will only provide a 'sandboxed' environment in which some Lua language elements are hidden from scripts. **module** is often hidden in such an environment.